# Inverting logarithmic scale to linear scale

Tags: math, logarithm

I got a code that consume value from 1 to 99 and output a logarithmic value using following equation:

Value = clamp(math::pow(2, 10.0* input / 99)/800, 0.0, 1.0)

Now i need to invert that, like given the logarithmic value, i need it to convert it within the linear range from 1 to 99.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear whether you are asking for help with algebra (inverting the formula) or with programming (converting the formula into code). If algebra, then you should ask on a math site. if programming, then show us the formula you are trying to convert to code, share what you've written so far, and we can try to fix it.

Comment: If it is just algebra, then you are looking for `input = 99 * log(800 * value) / (10 * log(2))`, where `log` is any logarithm.

Comment: Yep, got it working. I'll post detail soon. Thanks.